# Linq / Entity Group by then count those groups

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am having trouble doing the following:

1. Count the number of times column x = "foo" appears
2. and return the a list of <"foo", Count("foo")>

Example:

```
Id    Name
1    Ted
2    Ted
3    Ben
4    Ben
5    Ben
6    Cop
7    Null
8    Null
9    Null

Resulting list would be:

List<Count,Value>
     <Ted,2>
     <Ben,3>
     <Cop,1>
     <Null,3>
```

I am new to linq/Entity and just can not figure it out.

I have the following:

```
var names= db.User.GroupBy(fu => fu.Name)
                  .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

But, this only let me select by Key, I want this:

```
    var names= db.User.GroupBy(fu => fu.Name)
                  .Select(g => new { g.Name, Count = g.Count() });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close. 
Try following

```
var names= db.User.GroupBy(fu => fu.Name)
              .Select(g => new { Name=g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 var names= db.User.GroupBy(fu => fu.Name)
                  .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```